# Flat addresses for TEBs in another process?

Tags: windows, systems-programming, win32-process, win64

Win32 system structures like TEB, PEB and so on are easy to find for the current process, by accessing the TIB relative to FS/GS like NtCurrentTeb() and the TLS functions do.

Doing the same in another process would require code injection for performing accesses relative to FS/GS, or knowledge of the flat address of some key data item so that the process info structures can be walked using ReadProcessMemory().

What would be the best - most stable, least undocumented - way of accomplishing the latter? In case it matters, at the moment I'm mostly interested in accessing TLS data.

Answer (score 1):

Matt Pietrek's "Under the Hood" column for August 2004 [*Reading another process's environment*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt_pietrek/archive/2004/08/25/220330.aspx) mentions the **[NtQueryInformationProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** function.

For information class 0 (ProcessBasicInformation) it returns a structure that contains a pointer to the PEB, among other things. The function comes with some health warnings and it is not contained in the standard import libraries of the Windows SDK, but a declaration for it is available in `<winternl.h>` so that the result of GetProcAddress() can be typed correctly.

A file named [utility.cpp](http://web-athentication.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/MalwareCode/Myth/Utility.cpp) on Google Code demonstrates how to use **[GetThreadSelectorEntry()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** to obtain the selector base for a given selector in a given thread. With the actual values of the segment registers available via [GetThreadContext()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this allows it to resolve segmented user-space addresses to linear addresses for use with ReadProcessMemory(). These functions are part of the core debugger support and hence reliably available.

WOW64 adds a few minor twists ([Wow64GetThreadContext()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) etc.) but no serious complications.

Tested on XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8.1.